# consolidate rows and sum in R

Tags: r

I have a relatively large dataset (~9000 rows/observations) and aim to estimate tradeflows. To that end, I have a dataset that contains in its first column a unique identifier for the country pairs and the year,  indicating the importer and exporter, and year respectively, I.e.

```
> head(data)
               cp    id_IM    id_EX iso2_a iso2_t Freq value  date_c
1 AD_2015_ES_2015 AD_2015 ES_2015     AD     ES    2 20775   2015
2 AD_2015_ES_2015 AD_2015 ES_2015     AE     AM    2 20000   2015
3 AE_2008_AT_2008 AE_2008 AT_2008     AE     AT    1    25   2008
4 AE_2008_EG_2008 AE_2008 EG_2008     AE     EG    1   393   2008
5 AE_2008_GB_2008 AE_2008 GB_2008     AE     GB    2  8896   2008
6 AE_2008_GB_2008 AE_2008 GB_2008     AE     GB    2 59856   2008   2008
```

I have then consolidated the country pairs so that I only have one country pair for each year and summed

```
agg <- zephyr %>% ddply(.
(cp, id_a, id_t, iso2_a, iso2_t, date_a, date_c, Freq), 
function(x) c(value=sum(x$value)))
```

although I am also not sure whether R has actually done what I wanted. My problems are thus:

(1) how can I sum the value column but not all other columns and delete the duplicates so that I have one country pair for each year with the sum value of all duplicates, i.e.

```
               cp    id_IM    id_EX iso2_a iso2_t Freq value  date_c
1 AD_2015_ES_2015 AD_2015 ES_2015     AD     ES    2 20775   2015
2 AD_2015_ES_2015 AD_2015 ES_2015     AD     ES    2 20000   2015
```

becomes

```
               cp    id_IM    id_EX iso2_a iso2_t Freq value date_c
1 AD_2015_ES_2015 AD_2015 ES_2015     AD     ES    2   40775  2015
```

(2) As I want the full trade flow between country a and b, I also need to sum the flow from a to b with the flow from b to a. In other words,
how can I sum

```
               cp    id_IM    id_EX iso2_a iso2_t Freq value  date_c
1 AD_2015_ES_2015 AD_2015 ES_2015     AD     ES    1 20775   2015
2 ES_2015_AD_2015 ES_2015 AD_2015     ES     AD    1 20000   2015
```

so that these two observation remain but their value is added:

```
               cp    id_IM    id_EX iso2_a iso2_t Freq value  date_c
1 AD_2015_ES_2015 AD_2015 ES_2015     AD     ES    1 40775   2015
2 ES_2015_AD_2015 ES_2015 AD_2015     ES     AD    1 40775   2015
```

Thank you very much for your help as I am really struggling with this as a total beginner.

Comment: `zephyr %>% group_by(cp, id_IM, id_EX, iso2_a, iso2_t, date_c) %>% summarize(Freq_value=sum(`Freq value`))`

Comment: Thank you! That answers the part to (1). However, (2) remains. How can I now sum the observation A_2000_B_2000 and B_2000_A_2000 so that both have the sum but remain in the dataset?

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? given the current structure of your data frame, you can't do this because you don't have a variable that would uniquely identify this scenario to replace your `cp` and `id_IM` columns when you collapse the numeric variables onto one row.